# %matplotlib inline magic command fails to read variables from previous cells in AWS-EMR Jupyterhub Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I'm trying to plot spark dataset using matplotlib after converting it to pandas dataframe in AWS EMR jupyterhub.

I'm able to plot in a single cell using matplotlib like below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = [1, 1.6, 3, 4.2, 5, 4, 2.5, 3, 1.5]
plt.plot(df)
```

*Now the above code snippet works pretty neatly for me.*

After this sample example, I moved ahead to plot my pandas dataframe from a new/multiple cells in AWS-EMR Jupyterhub like this:

```
-Cell 1-
sparkDS=spark.read.parquet('s3://bucket_name/path').cache()


-Cell 2-
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
sparkDS_groupBy=sparkDS.groupBy('col1').agg(count('*').alias('count')).orderBy('col1')
pandasDF=sparkDS_groupBy.toPandas()


-cell 3-
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(pandasDF)
```

My code just fails in cell 3 with the following error:

***NameError: name 'pandasDF' is not defined***

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Why the new cell in my jupyterhub notebook is not able to recognize a variable from the previous cell?

Does it have to do something with the '%matplotlib inline' magic command (I tried with '%matplotlib notebook' also, but failed)?

ps: I'm using AWS 5.19 EMR-Jupyterhub notebook setup for my plotting work.

*This error is kind of similar to this one, but not a duplicate*
[How do I make matplotlib work in AWS EMR Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264957/how-do-i-make-matplotlib-work-in-aws-emr-jupyter-notebook/56508998#56508998)

Comment: I can't see you defining ```pandasDF``` anywhere in the above code. Is there some code you're not showing us?

Comment: I'm converting spark dataset to pandas dataframe in the second cell third line, like this:
pandasDF=sparkDS_groupBy.toPandas()

Comment: Try to simplify the problem. Can you print the dataframe? If not, remove matplotlib from the equation. Can you use a python list instead of a dataframe to get the same error? If so, remove pandas from the problem, etc. etc.

Comment: printing the dataframe itself gives an error.
Seems like matplotlib has an issue with pyspark kernel. 
in python kernel it runs fine

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into the `%%spark -o df_name` and `%%local` functions, by typing `%%help` in a cell.

Specifically, in your case try:

1. Use `%%spark -o sparkDS_groupBy` at the start of `-Cell 2-`,
2. Start `-Cell 3-` with `%%local`,
3. And plot `sparkDS_groupBy` in `-Cell 3-` instead of `pandasDF`.

---

For those with less context, you can get plots by implementing the following in an EMR Notebook using PySpark kernel, attached to an EMR cluster that's at least version 5.26.0 (which introduces [Notebook-Scoped Libraries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-scoped-libraries.html).

(each code block represents a Cell)

```
%% help
```

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf":{
"spark.pyspark.python": "python3",
"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true",
"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type":"native",
"spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path":"/usr/bin/virtualenv"
}}
```

```py
sc.install_pypi_package("matplotlib")
```

```py
%%spark -o my_df
# in this cell, my_df is a pyspark.sql.DataFrame
my_df = sc.read.text("s3://.../...")
```

```
%%local
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# in this cell, my_df is a pandas.DataFrame
plt.plot(my_df)
```

Comment: Note that there may be a limitation to the `-o` flag. It seems that only the last `-o` flag's value is respected per `%%spark`. If that's the case, just use more than one `%%spark` declaration.

Comment: technically, `matplotlib` is available by default, so installing it is unnecessary.