# How to Pass Variable from EMR Cluster to Jupyter Notebook %%local Instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, amazon-emr

How do I use a variable defined in the EMR cluster's Python instance when I run code on the managed Jupyter notebook instance using `%%local`?

Specifically I want to use matplotlib as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56264957/how-do-i-make-matplotlib-work-in-aws-emr-jupyter-notebook), and display plot from a dataframe generated using `spark.sql()`. Using `%%sql` lets me easily use data results in `%%local`, but I would still need to pass parameters to `%%sql` from the EMR Python instance

Example:

```
ln[1]: parameter = 'Hello parameter'

ln[2]: %%local
       print(parameter)
```

I keep getting error that my variable is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 workarounds

- Use `%%spark -o df` to return SQL query results to a dataframe that can be used with `%%local` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516346/matplotlib-inline-magic-command-fails-to-read-variables-from-previous-cells-in)
- Do all query building, execution and any data processing like normal without using any `%%` magic commands, then write the final data to a temporary table in my database using `df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table_name")`. Then use a simple query to retrieve the final data with `%%sql -q -o df` and `SELECT * FROM temp_table_name`